# Getting inside a Openshift container using Ansible/Python

Tags: python, ansible, openshift

I was trying to automate the process of getting/copying a file from a POD to the jump node of an  Openshift cluster(not using the `rsync` command). I tried to find any suitable ansible module for this but failed and tried to create a python script also but not sure how will I manage the authentication part. So if you have any example repo/website from where I can get an idea on how to write a python script for this or any official Ansible module that is suitable for this task please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find that [`connection: kubectl`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/connection/kubectl.html) doesn't work for you?